# T-SQL match two tables based on matching criteria/rules

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm trying to find an efficient way of doing this matching process.  I'm not sure if set based updates are the way to go or if a cursor should be used.  I'd like to have the matching rules in a separate table as shown below (so that they don't have to be hard-coded in the stored procedure).  This is in SQL Server 2014.

I have two tables I need to match based on a set of matching rules/criteria (in a third table).  I'm trying to find an efficient method to accomplish this.

Here's the situation:  we have payments that need to match to bookings - in order to do this we'll have a set of matching rules that we can go by.  I'll need to match the tables based on those rules and update the data in the payment table with the match_code (the rule that was used to update the data).

Payments table:

```
╔═══════════╦══════════╦══════════════╦════════════╦═══════╦════════════╗
║ FirstName ║ LastName ║ Confirmation ║    Date    ║ Trans ║ Match_code ║
╠═══════════╬══════════╬══════════════╬════════════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ Scott     ║ Bloom    ║       123456 ║ 2016-01-15 ║       ║            ║
║ Beverly   ║ Smith    ║        65487 ║ 2016-08-16 ║       ║            ║
║ Cindy     ║ Plum     ║       147852 ║ 2016-07-19 ║       ║            ║
╚═══════════╩══════════╩══════════════╩════════════╩═══════╩════════════╝
```

Bookings table:

```
╔═══════════╦══════════╦══════════════╦════════════╦═════════════╗
║ FirstName ║ LastName ║ Confirmation ║    Date    ║ Transaction ║
╠═══════════╬══════════╬══════════════╬════════════╬═════════════╣
║ Alfred    ║ Kim      ║       987456 ║ 2016-11-17 ║       12345 ║
║ Beverly   ║ Smith    ║        65487 ║ 2016-07-14 ║       12346 ║
║ Cindy     ║ Plum     ║        99898 ║ 2016-07-19 ║       12347 ║
╚═══════════╩══════════╩══════════════╩════════════╩═════════════╝
```

Rules table:

```
╔════════════╦═══════════╦══════════╦══════════════╦══════╗
║ Match_code ║ FirstName ║ LastName ║ Confirmation ║ Date ║
╠════════════╬═══════════╬══════════╬══════════════╬══════╣
║          1 ║         1 ║        1 ║            1 ║    1 ║
║          2 ║         1 ║        1 ║            1 ║    0 ║
║          3 ║         1 ║        1 ║            0 ║    1 ║
╚════════════╩═══════════╩══════════╩══════════════╩══════╝
```

The rules table identifies which fields are required to be considered a match for each Match_code

The matching procedure should run through and try to match the payments to bookings based on the match rules.

- It would try to update based on match code 1 and finds that there are no exact matches on all columns.
- It tries match code 2 and finds one match (Beverly matches on first, last, confirmation but not date).
- It tries match code 3 and finds one match (Cindy matches on first, last, date, but not confirmation).

The procedure should update the payments.trans field and the payments.match_code field based on the match it found in the bookings table.  The result would be this:

Payments table:

```
╔═══════════╦══════════╦══════════════╦════════════╦═══════╦════════════╗
║ FirstName ║ LastName ║ Confirmation ║    Date    ║ Trans ║ Match_code ║
╠═══════════╬══════════╬══════════════╬════════════╬═══════╬════════════╣
║ Scott     ║ Bloom    ║       123456 ║ 2016-01-15 ║       ║          0 ║
║ Beverly   ║ Smith    ║        65487 ║ 2016-08-16 ║ 12346 ║          2 ║
║ Cindy     ║ Plum     ║       147852 ║ 2016-07-19 ║ 12347 ║          3 ║
╚═══════════╩══════════╩══════════════╩════════════╩═══════╩════════════╝
```

The result is that we now know for each payment which booking it matched to and which match_code it matched on.

If you have any recommendations for the best way to accomplish a task like this it would be greatly appreciated - thanks in advance!

Comment: upvoted for good formatting in your first post itself.. I don't see many people doing this though SO provides so many hints to format the question

Comment: @Prdp I agree but cant follow the rules matching explanation :(

Comment: You can try using MERGE in T-SQL. It will not be very flexible, that is if you add an extra matching column to Rules table you would need to modify your MERGE statement. I am not sure if this is good enough.

Comment: Wouldnt be easy include the transaction asociate to each payment at the moment of save the payment? I understand if you cant change it, but UI should be able to register what booking is user trying to pay

Comment: are you expected to use the rules table as a data source, or just a reference for your SQL?  If/when the rules change, do you need the same SQL to work?

Comment: @beth that's the idea - use the rules table as the data source.  The rules could be changed or new ones added in the future and the same SQL should pick up those rules at the time and work

Comment: @Prdp thanks!  I wanted my first question to be well presented

Comment: @Andrew, if that's the case, I think they should have set it up differently for you so you could use dynamic SQL.  It would be easier to work with if the rules table had columns field1AND, field2AND, field3AND... and the value was the name of the field to match instead of 0/1.  Then you could use dynamic SQL to build your query.

Comment: @Andrew, how complete is your sample data?  Does it exactly match what your schema, or are there really several more fields that could potentially be matched on?  What's the worst case number of fields they could match on and is it very unlikely they'll ever add more?

Answer (score 1):

Assuming your rules are static and never change (I know this is not the case,) I'd do something like:

```
WITH p (paymentID, rule1Key, rule2Key, rule3Key) AS 
(SELECT
paymentID, 
firstname + '|' + lastname + '|' + confirmation + '|' + [DATE] AS rule1Key,
firstname + '|' + lastname + '|' + confirmation  AS rule2Key,
firstname + '|' + lastname + '|' + [DATE] AS rule3Key
FROM
payment),

b (TRANSACTION, rule1Key, rule2Key, rule3Key) AS
(SELECT
[TRANSACTION], 
firstname + '|' + lastname + '|' + confirmation + '|' + [DATE] AS rule1Key,
firstname + '|' + lastname + '|' + confirmation  AS rule2Key,
firstname + '|' + lastname + '|' + [DATE] AS rule3Key
FROM
bookings)

UPDATE p
SET trans = 
    CASE 
        WHEN b1 IS NOT NULL THEN    b1.TRANSACTION
        WHEN b2 IS NOT NULL THEN    b2.TRANSACTION
        WHEN b3 IS NOT NULL THEN    b3.TRANSACTION
    end,
SET match_code = 
    CASE 
        WHEN b1 IS NOT NULL THEN    1
        WHEN b2 IS NOT NULL THEN    2
        WHEN b3 IS NOT NULL THEN    3
    end
FROM
p LEFT OUTER JOIN
b b1 ON
p.rule1key = b1.rule1key LEFT OUTER JOIN
b b2 ON
p.rule2key = b2.rule2key LEFT OUTER JOIN
b b3 ON
p.rule3key = b3.rule3key;
```

Understanding, however, your evil users want to play with the rules (they won't like their current restrictions, they'll be asking for <, >, and OR conditions later, mark my words!  When they ask for () you revolt!

then you need them to structure the table differently for you so you can use dynamic sql to build your query from the contents of the rules table.  They could have a 2-column table with the matchID and fieldName and assume they're always connected by AND conditions, so your rules would look like:

```
matchID   fieldName
1         FirstName 
1         LastName 
1         Confirmation 
1         DATE
2         FirstName 
2         LastName 
2         Confirmation 
3         FirstName 
3         LastName 
3         DATE
```

Hopefully you can see how to get from those rule contents to a query you can generate to do your update.

Comment: Maybe you want check my answer for another perspective.

Comment: @Beth this is really interesting, thank you so much!  We definitely would end up doing the relative conditions (such as date plus/minus 2 days).  I like the idea of restructuring the rules table to be 2 columns.  Assuming we did that,  how would you take that from the rules table into the query?

Comment: @Andrew yep, just as I suspected.  If they want a different operation than equality, you'll have to support another column with the operator (matchSequence/fieldname/operation, defaults to equals, you define other values like date+-2) but really they're going to be disappointed in this solution no matter what you do, you can't guarantee you'll find the appropriate match with an automated solution, no matter what rules they want to apply.  I'd consider bringing bigger guns into the conversation with the customers.

Comment: @Andrew, regarding creating your query plugging in rules content, I'd use a programming environment instead of SQL, because it's easy for a programmer to use a rules table and template SQL to fill in the blanks.  Should only take a few minutes to create, but you need approval on the changes to the schema and some agreement with your boss and more senior DBAs that they want to invest in this solution, understanding the performance will always suck because of lack of indexes/tuning for queries.

Answer (score 0):

**[Sql Fiddle Demo](http://rextester.com/KJYZP59450)**

First you need to `LEFT JOIN` using `OR`, and use `CASE` to determinate where the match occurs.

```
SELECT P.[FirstName], P.[LastName], P.[Confirmation], P.[Date], B.[Transaction],
       CASE WHEN P.[FirstName]     = B.[FirstName]    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as match_1,
       CASE WHEN P.[LastName]      = B.[LastName]     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as match_2,
       CASE WHEN P.[Confirmation]  = B.[Confirmation] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as match_3,
       CASE WHEN P.[Date]          = B.[Date]         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as match_4
FROM Payments P
LEFT JOIN Bookings B
  ON P.[FirstName]     = B.[FirstName]
  OR P.[LastName]      = B.[LastName]
  OR P.[Confirmation]  = B.[Confirmation]
  OR P.[Date]          = B.[Date]
```

**Partial Output:** `P.* + B.[Transaction] + match.*`

[image]

Then you use that query to check what rules follow

```
WITH cte as (
    SELECT P.[FirstName], P.[LastName], P.[Confirmation], P.[Date], B.[Transaction],
           CASE WHEN P.[FirstName]     = B.[FirstName]    THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as match_1,
           CASE WHEN P.[LastName]      = B.[LastName]     THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as match_2,
           CASE WHEN P.[Confirmation]  = B.[Confirmation] THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as match_3,
           CASE WHEN P.[Date]          = B.[Date]         THEN 1 ELSE 0 END as match_4
    FROM Payments P
    LEFT JOIN Bookings B
      ON P.[FirstName]     = B.[FirstName]
      OR P.[LastName]      = B.[LastName]
      OR P.[Confirmation]  = B.[Confirmation]
      OR P.[Date]          = B.[Date]  
)
SELECT C.[FirstName], C.[LastName], C.[Confirmation], C.[Date], C.[Transaction], 
      COALESCE([Match_code], 0 ) as [Match_code]
FROM cte C
LEFT JOIN Rules R
   ON C.match_1 = R.[FirstName]
  AND C.match_2 = R.[LastName]
  AND C.match_3 = R.[Confirmation]
  AND C.match_4 = R.[Date]
```

**Final Output**

[image]

**Final Note**

Is possible your payment match one or more booking, also is possible match different rules. So you probably need use the last result as a subquery to select the lowest `[Match_code]`

Comment: you're assuming these are the only columns they'll ever match on and not a simplified example.  Yes, 4 columns is fine to hard-code, but what if he ends up with 20?

Comment: @Beth You are right, I tought the dynamic part was the number of rules on that universe, not the universe will change.

Comment: @Beth you are exactly right, the rules are simplified examples and we would likely grow to 20-30 rules

Answer (score 0):

I agree with Beth that this would be much simpler with a 2-column table (matchID, fieldname).

There are a number of different approaches to this.  One possibility would be to do something like the following, assuming that a primary key of some sort (id) exists in the payments and bookings table:

```
select payments.id, rules.match_Code, 
SUM(CASE WHEN payments.Firstname = bookings.FirstName 
       and rules.fieldname = 'Firstname' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN payments.lastname = bookings.lastname 
       and rules.fieldname = 'Lastname' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END +
    CASE WHEN payments.confirmation = bookings.confirmation 
       and rules.fieldname = 'confirmation' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS Matches 
from bookings, payments, rules
group by payments.id, bookings.id, rules.match_Code
```

From this you could compare the total number of matches to the total number of rules for any particular match code:

```
SELECT Match_Code, Count(*) AS Rules 
FROM Rules
GROUP BY Match_Code
```

If the number of matches equals the count of rules, you know you have a match for that code.  Then it's simply a matter of picking the lowest level match code for anyone one payment id:

```
FirstName   LastName    match_Code  Matches
Beverly     Smith       1           3
Beverly     Smith       2           3* 
Beverly     Smith       3           2
Cindy       Plum        1           3
Cindy       Plum        2           2
Cindy       Plum        3           3*
```

I know this isn't truly dynamic and I don't know about performance issues, but it's pretty simple to add fields to the CASE WHEN statement as needed and still make changes to the rules definitions on demand.

Comment: thank you!  I like the way you did this but the sum won't equal the match_code.  In my example match_code 1 had 4 columns matching and codes 2-3 had 3 matching in each

Comment: yes, the sum will be the number of matching fields for a particular match code.  So match_code 1 has 4 columns, and in this example Matches would not equal 4 for any of the given rows.  But match_code 2 and 3 each have 3 fields.  Both Beverly Smith and Cindy Plum will return Matches = 3 for their respective match codes (Beverly Smith = match_code 2, Cindy Plum = match_code 3).  So those are valid matches.  You still have to match on match_code in each case if that makes sense.

Answer (score 0):

**Updated with loopless alternative!**

This answers the question, but that doesn't mean it's a good idea.

Note that it should be wrapped in a suitable transaction to ensure that updates to the `Payments` and `Bookings` tables don't cause any confusion while this mess is running.

It loops through the rules, in order, trying to find matches and updating `Payments` accordingly. It can be modified to perform the `update` using dynamic SQL so that the query optimizer can have a shot at improving the performance.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Payments as Table ( FirstName VarChar(10), LastName VarChar(10), PaymentDate Date, Confirmation Int, TransactionId Int, MatchCode Int );
insert into @Payments ( FirstName, LastName, Confirmation, PaymentDate, TransactionId, MatchCode ) values
  ( 'Scott', 'Bloom', 123456, '20160115', NULL, NULL ),
  ( 'Beverly', 'Smith', 65487, '20160816', NULL, NULL ),
  ( 'Cindy', 'Plum', 147852, '20160719', NULL, NULL );
select * from @Payments;

declare @Bookings as Table ( FirstName VarChar(10), LastName VarChar(10), PaymentDate Date, Confirmation Int, TransactionId Int );
insert into @Bookings ( FirstName, LastName, Confirmation, PaymentDate, TransactionId ) values
  ( 'Alfred', 'Kim', 987456, '20161117', 12345 ),
  ( 'Beverly', 'Smith', 65487, '20160714', 12346 ),
  ( 'Cindy', 'Plum', 99898, '20160719', 12347 );
select * from @Bookings;

declare @Rules as Table ( MatchCode Int, FirstName Bit, LastName Bit, Confirmation Bit, PaymentDate Bit );
insert into @Rules ( MatchCode, FirstName, LastName, Confirmation, PaymentDate ) values
  ( 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ),
  ( 2, 1, 1, 1, 0 ),
  ( 3, 1, 1, 0, 1 );
select * from @Rules;

-- Process the data.
declare @MatchCode Int, @FirstName Bit, @LastName Bit, @Confirmation Bit, @PaymentDate Bit;
declare MatchPattern Cursor for
  select MatchCode, FirstName, LastName, Confirmation, PaymentDate
    from @Rules
    order by MatchCode;
open MatchPattern;
fetch next from MatchPattern into @MatchCode, @FirstName, @LastName, @Confirmation, @PaymentDate;
-- Apply the matching rules in order.
while @@Fetch_Status = 0
  begin
  update @Payments
    set MatchCode = @MatchCode, TransactionId = B.TransactionId
    from @Payments as P inner join
      @Bookings as B on
        ( B.FirstName = P.FirstName or @FirstName = 0 ) and
        ( B.LastName = P.LastName or @LastName = 0 ) and
        ( B.Confirmation = P.Confirmation or @Confirmation = 0 ) and
        ( B.PaymentDate = P.PaymentDate or @PaymentDate = 0 )
    where P.MatchCode is NULL -- Skip any rows which have already been matched.
  fetch next from MatchPattern into @MatchCode, @FirstName, @LastName, @Confirmation, @PaymentDate;
  end;
close MatchPattern;
deallocate MatchPattern;

-- Handle any   Payments   that were not matched.
update @Payments
  set MatchCode = 0
  where MatchCode is NULL;

-- Display the result.
select * from @Payments;
```

Alternatively, if you think a `cross join` will improve performance because All Cursors Are Evil℠. This is the SQL Super Collider approach: try smashing `Payments` against `Bookings` and seeing if the results happen to match any of the `Rules`.

```
-- Sample data.
declare @Payments as Table ( FirstName VarChar(10), LastName VarChar(10), PaymentDate Date, Confirmation Int, TransactionId Int, MatchCode Int );
insert into @Payments ( FirstName, LastName, Confirmation, PaymentDate, TransactionId, MatchCode ) values
  ( 'Scott', 'Bloom', 123456, '20160115', NULL, NULL ),
  ( 'Beverly', 'Smith', 65487, '20160816', NULL, NULL ),
  ( 'Cindy', 'Plum', 147852, '20160719', NULL, NULL );
select * from @Payments;

declare @Bookings as Table ( FirstName VarChar(10), LastName VarChar(10), PaymentDate Date, Confirmation Int, TransactionId Int );
insert into @Bookings ( FirstName, LastName, Confirmation, PaymentDate, TransactionId ) values
  ( 'Alfred', 'Kim', 987456, '20161117', 12345 ),
  ( 'Beverly', 'Smith', 65487, '20160714', 12346 ),
  ( 'Cindy', 'Plum', 99898, '20160719', 12347 );
select * from @Bookings;

declare @Rules as Table ( MatchCode Int, FirstName Bit, LastName Bit, Confirmation Bit, PaymentDate Bit );
insert into @Rules ( MatchCode, FirstName, LastName, Confirmation, PaymentDate ) values
  ( 1, 1, 1, 1, 1 ),
  ( 2, 1, 1, 1, 0 ),
  ( 3, 1, 1, 0, 1 );
select * from @Rules;

-- Process the data.
declare @True as Bit = 1, @False as Bit = 0;
-- The following is based on the assumption that   Confirmation   uniquely identifies   Payments .
update @Payments
  set TransactionId = NewTransactionId, MatchCode = NewMatchCode from
  @Payments as P inner join (
    select P.Confirmation, Min( B.TransactionId ) as NewTransactionId, Coalesce( Min( R.MatchCode ), 0 ) as NewMatchCode
      from @Payments as P cross join
        @Bookings as B left outer join
        @Rules as R on
          R.FirstName = case when P.FirstName = B.FirstName then @True else @False end and
          R.LastName = case when P.LastName = B.LastName then @True else @False end and
          R.Confirmation = case when P.Confirmation = B.Confirmation then @True else @False end and
          R.PaymentDate = case when P.PaymentDate = B.PaymentDate then @True else @False end
      where P.MatchCode is NULL
      group by P.Confirmation ) as C on C.Confirmation = P.Confirmation;

-- Display the result.
select * from @Payments;
```